# How to programmatically use the built in search functionality

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, search-api

How to programmatically use the built in search functionality to get the results and displays in the app part?

I have found some jQuery REST search api code and it seems working when I try to add my own textbox and button to search results.

But what if i want to use built in search of SharePoint 2013. How to call?

Here is my function. But I'm not getting how to call it from built in search.

```
function getSearchResultsUsingREST() 
{
  var searchUrl = appweburl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + $get('searchText').value + "'";

  var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl.toLowerCase());
  executor.executeAsync(
  {
        url: searchUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: onGetSearchResultsSuccess,
        error: onGetSearchResultsFail
  });
}
```

I want to display the results in my app part .

Comment: did you consider using OOTB Search results webpart or Content Search webpart instead of App part?

Comment: **actually no**

Comment: @Unnie he wants to show the search result in SharePoint App, I am not aware of how to add webpart in App's default.aspx page. If you know then please let us know. Thanks.



Meet :-query which your are querying is correct but i will suggest you to use the existing result source or create new one and then get results from that Result Source.
below link will help you:-
http://techmikael.blogspot.ae/2015/01/how-to-query-using-result-source-name.html

Comment: i didnt get what u mean by existing source? when searching for some data from list the app part should use search to find all items from the list or content type that i require